# Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.5.3 Too many recipients (AS780090)

Tags: smtp

Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.5.3 Too many recipients (AS780090)

Line 121:        Dim mSmtpClient As New SmtpClient()
Line 122:
**Line 123:        mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage)**

```html
   Public Function SendMail(ByVal emailto As String, ByVal strtitle As String, ByVal strmsg As String) As String
        ' Try

        Dim mMailMessage As New MailMessage()
        Dim from1 As String = "*******@*****.com"
        ' Set the sender address of the mail message 
        mMailMessage.From = New MailAddress(from1, strtitle)
        ' Set the recepient address of the mail message 
        mMailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress(emailto, strtitle))
        mMailMessage.Subject = strtitle


        mMailMessage.Subject = strtitle

        'mMailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress(email).ToString)
        mMailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress(emailto).ToString)

        ' Set the format of the mail message body as HTML 
        mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
        'mMailMessage.Body = strmsg
        mMailMessage.Body = strmsg


        ' Set the priority of the mail message to normal 
        mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High
        mMailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256")
        mMailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256")

        ' Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient 
        Dim mSmtpClient As New SmtpClient()

        mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage)


    End Function
```

What is solution for this error ??or where is my code wrong ??
I have added the code too ,please review my code !

Answer (score 0):

There is some limit to how many recipients can be added in one single email. Recipients include:

- To
- CC
- BCC

In gmail its set to 100 for different mail provider its diff value.

If you are sending more than that no of ID in single email then it will give this error